# Как значение input передать в функцию?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть готовая функция JS. У неё есть аргументы. Как задать их при помощи ввода input? Как реализовать это в HTML?

```
function setCookie(name, value, options) {
  options = options || {};

  var expires = options.expires;

  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
    expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
    options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }

  value = encodeURIComponent(value);

  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
    if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
    }
  }

  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
```

Comment: Andrew Feshyk, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Перед функцией пропиши это для каждой переменной `name=document.getElementById("name_id").value; //получаем значение из поля в html`

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

*HTML*:

```
<form action="form.php" onsubmit="return onSubmit(this)">
    <input type="text" name="name1">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

*JavaScript*:

```
function onSubmit(obj)
{
    setCookie('name1', obj.name1.value);
    //если форму после setCookie надо отправлять на сервер, то замените ниже false на true:
    return false;
}
```